# Error: can't resolve multiple constant driver (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, error

trying to solve this error but none of it work. It says 
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "current_state.S4" at wood_detector.vhd(23)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity wood_detector is
port(clk,rst: in std_logic; 
AB: in std_logic_vector( 1 downto 0) ;
z: out std_logic);
end wood_detector;

architecture fsm of wood_detector is
type t_state is (S0, S1, S2, S3, S4);
signal current_state, next_state: t_state;

begin
process(clk,rst)
begin 
    if(rst = '1') then current_state<= S0;
    elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then current_state <= next_state;
end if;
end process;

process(current_state,AB)
begin
case(current_state) is
when S0 => if(AB="10") then next_state<=S1;
                else next_state<=S0;
                end if;
when S1 => if(AB="00") then next_state <= S2;
                    elsif(AB="11") then next_state <= S3;
                else current_state <= S1;
                end if;
when S2 => if(AB="01") then next_state <= S4;
                else next_state <= S2;
                end if;
when S3 => if(AB="01") then next_state <= S4;
                else next_state <= S3;
                end if;

when others=>NULL;
end case;
end process;


z <= '1' when (current_state <= S2 and AB="00") else '0';

end fsm;
```

Comment: Your process includes `current state` in the sensitivity list, and modifies it. I think the `current_state <= S1` should read `next_state <= S1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are driving 'current' state in two processes. You should drive only from one process. (Or you have to make a resolution function which you probably do not want to do)